# Microsoft.Graph.GraphServiceClient Planner Buckets AddAsync returns error "Write requests are only supported on contained entities"

Tags: c#, office365, microsoft-graph-api

I have some code which will get or create a [Planner](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/planner-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0) [Bucket](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/plannerbucket?view=graph-rest-1.0).

```
public async Task<PlannerBucket> GetOrCreateBucket(GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient, string planId, string name)
{
    var buckets = await graphServiceClient
        .Planner
        .Plans[planId]
        .Buckets
        .Request()
        .GetAsync();

    var bucket = buckets.SingleOrDefault(b => b.Name.Equals(name));

    if (bucket == null)
    {
        bucket = await graphServiceClient
            .Planner
            .Plans[planId]
            .Buckets
            .Request()
            .AddAsync(new PlannerBucket()
            {
                Name = name
            });
    }

    return bucket;
}
```

When this code was originally written a year ago I'm fairly sure it worked okay.

Early on there was often new buckets and they were created okay.
Since then the create code has rarely been called, and recently when it is called it returns an error:

> Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: Code: BadRequest
>   Message: Write requests are only supported on contained entities

I'm not really sure what the error means.

What does it mean for an entity to be contained?
Why is it not contained?
Which entity does it even mean?
Does it mean the Bucket I'm trying to create?
Does it mean the Plan I'm trying to create it in?

The answer to these questions would be nice, as they'd help me understand how to fix the problem, but at the end of the day the real question is: "What am I doing wrong, and how do I correct it?".

Here's the HTTP request:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/planner/plans/__PLANID__/buckets HTTP/1.1
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer __TOKEN__
SdkVersion: Graph-dotnet-1.7.0
x-ms-request-root-id: 309b7fa3-4c57a2db0536dddc
x-ms-request-id: |309b7fa3-4c57a2db0536dddc.2.
Request-Id: |309b7fa3-4c57a2db0536dddc.2.1.
Content-Length: 30
Host: graph.microsoft.com

{"name":"__BUCKETNAME__"}
```

And here's the response:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Cache-Control: private
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json
request-id: 5186e2aa-7a1c-4f86-88c4-5542ef89e6c9
client-request-id: 5186e2aa-7a1c-4f86-88c4-5542ef89e6c9
x-ms-ags-diagnostic: __DIAGNOSTICINFO__
Duration: 2.7551
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
Date: Thu, 24 Jan 2019 13:08:52 GMT

fb
{
  "error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "Write requests are only supported on contained entities",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "5186e2aa-7a1c-4f86-88c4-5542ef89e6c9",
      "date": "2019-01-24T13:08:53"
    }
  }
}
0
```

Having searched around a bit, I think this issue has already been reported on github, but is currently still unresolved: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/307

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message here isn't very helpful, but the issue is that we don't allow POST to planner/plans/planid/buckets. You should be sending the request to planner/buckets and include the planid property in the body of the request. The example in the documentation is accurate (order hint is optional): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/planner-post-buckets?view=graph-rest-1.0

Comment: That worked great, thanks for showing me where I was going wrong.